# How to extract the message exactly in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, split

Below is my textbox which i store the output of my serial

[image]

Below is where i put the message inside the DataGridView the problem lies here see the last row of the grid there is an OK text.

[image]

[image]

my last photo shows the value of my line of text.

```
        Dim LineOfText As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim aryTextFile() As String

        LineOfText = tt.Text

        aryTextFile = Split(LineOfText, "+CMGL", , CompareMethod.Text)
        dgv.Rows.Clear()

        For i = 1 To UBound(aryTextFile)

            '**********************
            Dim LineOfTexts As String
            Dim aryTextFiles() As String
            LineOfTexts = aryTextFile(i)
            aryTextFiles = Split(LineOfTexts, """", , CompareMethod.Text)
            aryTextFiles(5) = aryTextFiles(5).Substring(0, 17).Replace(",", "-")

            dgv.Rows.Add(New String() {aryTextFiles(3), aryTextFiles(6), aryTextFiles(5)})


        Next i
```

is there any other way to extract the message exactly?
aryTextFiles(3) is the phone number/Sender aryTextFiles(6) is the message and  aryTextFiles(5) is the date and time.

Comment: If `LineOfText` will always end with "OK", you can use the `String.Substring` method to remove it before splitting it to create `aryTextFile`.

Comment: nope it doesn't always ends with "OK" sometimes RSSI something and OK pop out. see the last photo there is a 2 enter before the "OK" comes.

Comment: @Blackwood i already tried the substring method and it doesn't work

Comment: You will need to think about how you know that the OK is not part of the last message. Once you understand that, you can write code to exclude it.

Comment: Below the +CMGL is the message, but i don't know to to get it. i been working on this since yesterday and i think its time to ask here.

Comment: As I said, you need to ask yourself how you know that the "OK" is not part of the message (I don't know the answer to that). Once you know that, you can start to think about how to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last word by using Trim()

```
LineOfText = tt.Text.Substring(0, tt.Text.LastIndexOf(vbCrLf) - 3).Trim()
```

I used `-3` to trim the last 3 characters.